# If $T_k$ is a sequence of linear operators on $X$ such that $T_kx$ $\rightarrow$ 0 $\forall$ x $\in$ $X$, then $\|T_k\|$ $\rightarrow$ 0

Tags: functional-analysis

I wrote a proof of this statement. I know that this is incorrect since I could find counterexamples easily. It would have been true if $X$ is of finite dimension. The question is that I am not able to find the mistake in the following proof of mine.

$\forall$ $\varepsilon$ > 0, $\exists$ $x'$ $\in$ $X$ such that $\|x'\| = 1$ and
$\|T_k\|$= $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|T_kx\|$ < $\|T_kx'\|$ + $\varepsilon$/2.

By assumption, take $x$ = $x'$, $\forall$ $\varepsilon$ > 0, $\exists$ $K$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall$ k $\ge$ $K$, $\|T_kx'\|$ < $\varepsilon$/2.

Therefore, $\|T_k\|$ < $\varepsilon$.

Comment: The problem, or at least one problem, is that in the first display the $x'$ you get depends on $k$. In the second display you use the fact that $\lim_{k\to\infty}Tx'=0$, which would be given if $x'$ were a fixed vector, but which is actually not given, since it's actually $T_kx'_k$.

Comment: So, one approach would be to take one of your counterexamples, trace through your proof as applied to that counterexample, and see where the proof starts saying something false.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I am not sure about my understanding.
I think your idea is that in order to write the first line with the definition of supremum, we need a fixed k and x' depends on k. However, in the second line, k depends on the choice of x by assumption of pointwise convergent of $T_k$. 
Therefore x' depends on k and k depends on x' at the same time. This gives us the mistake am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $T_n: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ defined by $$T_k(x)=(0, ..., 0, x_{k+1}, ...)$$

Claim:

1. $(T_k(x)) \to 0$ $\quad \forall x\in\ell^2$
2. $\|T_k\|_{op}\not\to 0$

$($ Hint: It's easy to show that $\|T_k\|_{op}\ge 1$$)$